# Best way to process an uploaded JSON file locally (client) using JS

Tags: javascript, json, har

I want to upload a **HAR** file (which is based on the **JSON** format) and filter out all the unwanted private data like *cookies* etc. Basically, I need to create a new **JSON** file with the data from a selected group of fields and all of this has to happen locally on the client side (browser) before sending it to the server.

What is the best way to go about this using JS?

Comment: Just for context, why does it need to happen on the frontend?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier It's a school project prerequisite. I think the logic behind is to not store sensitive data on the server. It should be "cleaned out" before reaching the database.

Comment: Having sensitive data on the server is not necessarily a bad thing, sending something to the server does not mean that it's put in the database, unless you tell it to do so. But I digress. What have you come up with so far? You're asking about the *best* way, but that is suggestive. Besides that, your options are slim, since the prerequisite demands it to be a frontend solution. Show us your research and the solution you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file as a string then use `JSON.parse()` to load it as an object. Upon which you can transform it as you please.

I prefer using:

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  // do you transform here
},{});
```